# Generating a graphical object of a matrix's data and structure

Tags: r, matrix, plot, graphics

I'm looking to create hundreds of stimuli for a visual perception experiment by generating graphical object that represents a matrix's raw structure.

For this example, consider the matrix defined by:

```
set.seed(123)
a5 <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)  # Empty 5x5 matrix
a5l <- length(a5)  # Number of cells in array
ind <- sample(x = length(a5), replace = F, size = a5l)
a5[ind[1:12]] <- "X"
a5[ind[13:24]] <- "O"
a5[ind[25]] <- "T"
```

Which prints as:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "X"  "O"  "X"  "T"  "O" 
[2,] "O"  "X"  "O"  "X"  "X" 
[3,] "O"  "X"  "O"  "O"  "X" 
[4,] "O"  "O"  "O"  "X"  "O" 
[5,] "O"  "X"  "X"  "X"  "X"
```

What I'm hoping to generate is a object that visualizes the above structure and positioning of data with:

a) jitter on each point
b) colouring of the text

I'm sort of lost as to how to generate something like this. I was hoping to get an idea in the right direction if anyone has any experience.

My intuition tells me that it might be best to generate a long data.frame that has a factor variable defining position on X and another with position on Y with the value following.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to convert the letters to numbers and make a heatmap?

```
a5[ind[1:12]] <- 1
a5[ind[13:24]] <- 2
a5[ind[25]] <- 3

heatmap(a5, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = heat.colors(5), margins = c(5,5))
```

This could be associated with a legend that defines what each letter would be.

As for the "Jitter" on each point, I'm having a hard time understanding what this exactly is referring to.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Unfortunately I'm looking to get a raw output of the letters themselves. Something similar to this: http://imgur.com/a/Hjrfz   The jitter I was referring to was random noise added in the x,y placement of the object (as seen in the figure)